# Comparison of sum of vectors and exponential map on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, geodesics

Suppose $M$ is a simply-connected complete Riemannian manifold with bounded sectional curvature $\delta \leq K \leq \Delta < 0$. Let $p_0\in M$. Define the sequence of points $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ by
$$p_{k+1} = \exp_{p_{k}}(U_k), \quad U_k\in T_{p_k}M \text{ is some arbitrary vector}, k\geq 0. $$
The goal is to compare (e.g., give an upper bound for) $d(p_0, p_{n+1})$ with the norm of the sum of $U_k$s, that is, with
$$
\left\| U_1 + P_2U_2 + \cdots + P_nU_n \right\|,
$$
where $P_i$ is the parallel transport from $p_i$ to $p_0$. Is there a systematic way to do this?

My only shot is some technique (Jacobi field estimates) by Buser and Karcher [in this paper](http://www.numdam.org/issue/AST_1981__81__1_0.pdf) (6.6, page 105), but I cannot make it work for more than two vectors, as constructing a Jacobi field is not an obvious task. Any ideas on this?

[Original question on math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288760/comparison-of-sum-of-vectors-and-exponential-map-on-a-riemannian-manifold).

Comment: Only a vague idea: have you tried the Toponogov comparison theorem? This and many others are covered in a book by Cheeger and Ebin. Maybe you find something helpful there. Of course, that theorem would at first help only with two vectors, because you would need a good estimate on $\exp^{-1}_{p_0}(p_2)$ to continue. But my impression is that global comparison results might be more helpful than Jacobi field comparison.

Comment: Very good idea indeed! However, I was thinking that with Topogonov, I might be able to transfer the problem to a space with constant sectional curvature $\delta$. It is still unclear for me how to deal with this problem even in that case... (scratching my head)

Comment: In a space of constant curvature, there are trigonometric formulas that you can apply (for the first two vectors). Then you have to "guess" the next angle and continue ...